Water Cooling - Straight pipe vs. Coil Heat Exchanger
I have been looking at a heat exchanger design on the SolidWorks Flow Simulation toolbox. My goal is to cool down water from ambient temperature. To do so, the water flows through a cold aluminium block (at approx. 8 degrees C initial temperature) which has internal holes (8mm diameter). The block only has this initial cold temperature but is not cooled anymore when the water starts flowing. For both cases (straight pipes vs coil), I used the exact same simulation parameters. The flow rate of the water is 0.0076 kg/s, and I let the simulation run for 190 seconds (approx. 1.5 L of water). There is no heat exchange between the aluminium block and the surroundings, it is supposed perfectly isolated. So all the heat is exchanged only between the aluminium block and the water.
I have investigated the cooling of the water with the following system (see below), which has 5 straight holes which are interconnected with plastic tubes. The size of the block is 17x17x2cm and is made of aluminium. The results, which I have also tested myself in real life (results are very close), are the following. The water inlet temperature is 21 degrees C. For visualization, I have made the aluminium block transparent.

Now, when instead of having straight holes, I use a coil tubing (also 8mm diameter - see below), and by having a block of the same volume/mass (size of the block is 10x10x5.5cm) with the same internal pipe length (length of the coil is 860mm, whereas the length of the straight pipes above is 5x17cm=850mm) the results are very different. Left graph: water inlet temperature, right graph: water outlet temperature. Left graph: water inlet temperature, right graph: water outlet temperature. For visualization, I have made the aluminium block transparent.


One can see that the minimal water temperature is approx. 2 degrees C higher than in the case of the water cooling with straight pipes system. The average temperature for the straight pipe cooling system is approx. 17 degrees C, wheras it is
Does someone have a clue why the coil system cools the water less when the volume/mass and initial temperature of the aluminium blocks are the same in both cases, as well as the diameter and length of the internal hole/coil of 8mm is identical? What influences this outlet temperature of the water so much?
Thanks in advance for reading and helping out!
Fernand
EDIT:
To visualize better, the water flows through the block. The flow trajectories look like the following:

EDIT 2:
The average temperature of the aluminium block, for the first simulation:

And for the second simulation (with coil):

EDIT 3:
Results for coil simulation with larger distance between two subsequent coils. Top: temperature of water at inlet, middle: temperature of water at outlet, bottom figure: average temperature of aluminium block.


Hi there, I mentioned that "the water flows through a cold aluminium block", as well as the mass flow rate of the water. I'm not sure this is what you're referring to though?

No worries Daniel, I understand my question might be a little vague. There is maybe a bit too much information needed.
Yes exactly, you can see it as holes or pipes that are embedded in solid aluminium. In the case of the coil, it's a hollow coil that is casted in an aluminium block. For the straight pipes (case 1 in my OP), it are simple straight through holes in an aluminium block.
N.B. I added a picture (at the bottom of my OP) to show the flow trajectories!

Heat exchangers usually exchange heat between 2 fluids, so what you're investigating is a bit strange. Is it related to a real application, or are you just playing with the simulation?

Heat exchanger is not really the good term for my application, but yes it is related to a real application. I am trying to determine the best/optimal setup to cool down with a certain piping system that goes through a cold aluminium block. So following  the results, using a coil is not as optimal as using the straight pipe block (first simulation). Would you have any better ideas on how to get the maximum heat transfer for these 190 seconds of simulation?
